# OpencCV+Android+eclipse Windows 7 Installation

Tags: android, opencv, installation

I want to know how to install OpenCV in eclipse in Windows 7 64bit. I want use OpenCV functions to program my android application. My plan is to program in java code. I try various instructions but none of it worked. Does anybody know how to setup everything??

Comment: What are the instructions you have tried and why didn't it work out?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple:

1. Download the android sdk for OPEN CV
2. Extract the sdk to specified path
3. Open eclipse import existing android project to workspace select the location \sdk\java\
  and click finish.

Thats it you can use the OpenCV android library which is now present in your workspace to devel